# Method 'Run' of object 'IwshShell3' Failed while using Label

Tags: python, vba, string, shell

**UPDATE: I got it to work, you can look in the answers in case you're curious or have the same question.**

I wanted to make a macro to run code by first looking for a shell and then looking for a script and running it using a Wscript Shell.

I want to store the file paths in 2 labels and so I wrote this code:

```vb
Sub RunTerminal()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim CompilerExe, ScriptName As String
Dim StrCommand As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

CompilerExe = CStr(Slide1.Label2.Caption)
ScriptName = CStr(Slide1.Label1.Caption)

StrCommand = CompilerExe & ScriptName
objShell.Run StrCommand
End Sub
```

The code works when I specify the shell's file path there itself, like:

```vb
CompilerExe = """C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"""
```

but it does not when I specify it using the Label. The problem doesn't seem to occur with the script, though.

Here are the contents of Label1 and Label2 respectively.:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Arcade\coins.py
```

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I got it solved, here's how in case you have the same question:

I added `Chr(34)` before and after my file paths in case they had any spaces and it worked!

```vb
Sub RunTerminal()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim CompilerExe, ScriptName As String
Dim StrCommand As String

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

CompilerExe = Chr(34) & CStr(Slide1.Label2.Caption) & Chr(34)
ScriptName = Chr(34) & CStr(Slide1.Label1.Caption) & Chr(34)

StrCommand = CompilerExe & ScriptName
objShell.Run StrCommand
End Sub
```